# How can Excel VBA code sense when the user moves the application window?

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I need to keep a UserForm aligned along the right edge of the application's window. The UserForm.Layout event gets triggered when user moves the UserForm so the event handler can move the application window. How can VBA code sense when the user moves the application window so it can move the UserForm?

Comment: [Subclass](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20031111-00/?p=41883) `Application.Hwnd`, monitor for [`WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-windowposchanged). Or just poll `Application.Left`/`Top` with a timer.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. I neglected to say the program needs to work on Windows and Mac. I can't find any equivalent of HWnd functions on Mac so I'll look into polling.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.